# How to simplify these function template specializations?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

I am working on some legacy code that has the following template defined in a header file:

```
template<typename T>
std::string convertToString(const T& t);
```

In the same header file, there are  specializations for some user-defined types.  In the .cpp file, there are specializations for the types `int`, `unsigned short` and `unsigned long` as follows:

```
template<>
std::string convertToString<unsigned short>(const unsigned short& s) {
    ... some implementation ...
}

template<>
std::string convertToString<int>(const int & s) {
    ... some implementation ...
}

template<>
std::string convertToString<unsigned long>(const unsigned long& value) {
    ... some implementation ...
}
```

The implementations don't make use of C++11's `std::to_string` function.  I would like to simplify this code so that for all types that `std::to_string` supports, namely

```
int
long
long long
unsigned
unsigned long
unsigned long long
float
double
long double
```

the template specialization uses the simple implementation (e.g. for int):

```
template<>
std::string convertToString(const int& n) { return std::to_string(n); }
```

I could of course write down all template specializations for all the above mentioned types, but that doesn't seem like a nice way to do it.  My current best solution to have these template specializations for all types that `std::to_string` takes is to add the following to my header file:

```
template<typename T>
std::string convertToString(const T& t);

template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
std::string convertToString(const T& t)
{
    return std::to_string(t);
}
```

I think this is close to a solution, but not yet as I get the following ambiguity error:

```
error: call of overloaded 'convertToString(long unsigned int&)' is ambiguous
```

referring me to the above two template functions as possible candidates.  I don't quite understand why the first one is also a possible candidate if the second one exists...

How can I add template specializations for all the types that `std::to_string` supports, and also still allow for user-defined types T in the `convertToString` function template?  Solution should be restricted to C++11 for now...

UPDATE: adding a minimal working example below (code must be C++11):

So I want to replace the following code by something simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {};

template<typename T>
std::string convertToString(const T& t);

template<>
std::string convertToString(const int& n) { return std::to_string(n); }

template<>
std::string convertToString(const long& n) { return std::to_string(n); }

template<>
std::string convertToString(const long long& n) { return std::to_string(n); }

template<>
std::string convertToString(const unsigned& n) { return std::to_string(n); }

template<>
std::string convertToString(const unsigned long& n) { return std::to_string(n); }

template<>
std::string convertToString(const unsigned long long& n) { return std::to_string(n); }

template<>
std::string convertToString(const float& n) { return std::to_string(n); }

template<>
std::string convertToString(const double& n) { return std::to_string(n); }

template<>
std::string convertToString(const long double& n) { return std::to_string(n); }

template<>
std::string convertToString<A>(const A& a) { return std::string("foo"); }

int main()
{
    std::cout << convertToString(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(2L) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(3LL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(4U) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(5UL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(6ULL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(7.0f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(8.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(9.0L) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(A()) << std::endl;
}
```

I tried the folowing which gives me compiler errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};

template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
    std::string convertToString(const T& t);

template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
    std::string convertToString(const T& t)
{
    return std::to_string(t);
}

template<>
std::string convertToString<A>(const A& a) { return std::string("foo"); }

int main()
{
    std::cout << convertToString(A()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(2L) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(3LL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(4U) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(5UL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(6ULL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(7.0f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(8.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertToString(9.0L) << std::endl;
}
```

If someone could explain me what's wrong with this, that would be nice.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. I think its just one line to instantiate the template, simple for you to add, an obstacle for anybody who wants to write an answer (because they have to guess, and add the line)

Comment: includes are missing too. Please do not remove includes from the code before you post it.

Comment: I've added a minimal reproducible example in the meanwhile.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question like that after you've got an answer, but anyway [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76319921/3966456) may help.

Comment: I removed the part where you added the code from my answer. Please do not alter the question to ask for something else after you received answers. If you have a follow up quesiton you can open a new quesiton. Or you can ask for clarification on the given answers. If you change the quesiton like you did with your edit, you invalidate the already given answer, because they refer to a problem that isnt present anymore in your post

Comment: If one of the answers solves your problem, you should press the checkmark next to it to mark the question as solved.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I do understand that it gets confusing if I modify my question and start asking something new.  Thanks for cleaning up my question.  I'v also pressed the checkmark for the answer that solved my problem. (not saying that other alternatives couldn't have worked too though!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write two overloads with disjunct conditions for the SFINAE:

```
// overload for T is not is_arithmetic
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,std::string>::type convertToString(const T& t);

// overload for T is arithmetic
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,std::string>::type convertToString(const T& t)
{
    return std::to_string(t);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could create a type trait that checks if `std::to_string(t)` is valid and use SFINAE to only allow for the overloads that uses `std::to_string` to be instantiated if it's valid.

Type trait example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
using std::void_t;
#else
template <class...>
using void_t = void; // borrowed from C++17
#endif

template <class T, class = void>
struct has_to_string : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct has_to_string<T, void_t<decltype(std::to_string(std::declval<T>()))>>
    : std::true_type {};
```

Usage example:

```cpp
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<has_to_string<T>::value, std::string>::type
convertToString(const T& t) {
    return std::to_string(t);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following approach :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace traits {
// a compile-time check to see if the type matches a type we want to
// use std::to_string for
template <typename type_t>
constexpr bool use_std_string_convert() {
    return (std::is_integral<type_t>::value ||
            std::is_floating_point<type_t>::value) &&
           !std::is_same<type_t, bool>::value;
}
}  // namespace traits

// use SFINAE to enable this function only for integers and floats
template <typename type_t>
auto convertToString(const type_t& value) ->
    typename std::enable_if<traits::use_std_string_convert<type_t>(),
                            std::string>::type {
    std::string retval = std::to_string(value);
    std::cout << "converting an " << typeid(type_t).name()
              << " to string : " << retval << "\n";
    return retval;
}

// no need to use templates for special cases, just use normal overloading
std::string convertToString(bool value) {
    std::string retval = value ? "true" : "false";
    std::cout << "converting a bool to string : " << retval << "\n";
    return retval;
}

int main() {
    auto s1 = convertToString(1);
    auto s2 = convertToString(1.0);
    auto s3 = convertToString(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ted, indeed missed the C++11 detail ;)